# Dependency removal

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using rosdep it is possible to install system dependencies. Is there a command to uninstall the same system dependencies.

For example, you can do,

```
rosdep install rxtools
```

at the command line. Now is there any command to uninstall rxtools?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10271/dependency-removal/) by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-06-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get a list of debian packages required by a ROS package, you can run:

```
rosdep depdb rospackage(s) > debs.txt
```

Now you'll have to do some search-and-replace (or some nifty sed magic) to get a line-separated list of debian packages. Then you can run:

```
sudo xargs -d '\n' -a debs.txt aptitude markauto
```

... which will pipe the packages into `aptitude markauto`. Using `markauto` instead of `remove` has the advantage that only those packages are removed that are not needed by any other package in the system. Finally, run

```
aptitude
```

... to review the list of packages that would be removed (press '`g`'). If you want to keep some package, just highlight it and press '`+`' to mark it as "manually installed" again. Finally, press '`g`' again to remove the packages.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on 2011-06-17**:
Thank you very much - )

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-17**:
No, its all required packages. rosdep satisfy (without -i) will give you those which are not installed.

**Comment by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on 2011-06-17**:
So you mean to say that all the 'debian package' names that appear after "->" are the ones required by 'turtlesim' which are not installed on my computer?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-16**:
You will have lines like that: "<<<< zziplib -> libzzip-0-13 libzzip-dev >>>>". Ignore the brackets and everything on the left-hand side of "->". The debian package names here are libzzip-0-13 and libzzip-dev.

**Comment by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on 2011-06-16**:
Could you please explain to me the output of "rosdep depdb "? I tried "rosdep depdb turtlesim" and there was a confusing list of lines with left and right angle brackets, interparsed with names of various software..that I think is required by turtlesim.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-16**:
I would add one thing: For each dep in the debs.txt you should run "rosdep what_needs $dep" and include it only, if the result is empty (besides the package to delete). Otherwise system dependencies for ros packages, that are not installed as a .deb, might be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosdep satisfy -i PACKAGENAME` will list everything required by a package.  You can then apt-get remove whatever you want.  However be careful, other things may depend on some subset of that tree.  The best way to do what you want is likey to look in the dpkg logs of when you installed.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1